# What are the origins of the word "nice"?

Tags: etymology

The word "nice" tends to be used in rather a wishy-washy sense these days. In general use it tends to mean anything that is satisfactory.

But what are the origins of this word? What did it originally mean? Why has the meaning changed so much through the years?

Comment: No idea "nice" could have such an "unnice" history!

Comment: @Trifle: and at the same time it's a very nice history!

Comment: @Trifle. Think I could give you the history of "unnice" though. It starts and ends here. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question indeed!

It originally meant ['foolish, stupid':](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nice)

> 1250–1300; Middle English:  foolish, stupid

From [Etymonline.com:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=nice&searchmode=none)

> late 13c., "foolish, stupid, senseless

The following excerpt explains how the meaning of "nice" [became changed so much:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nice)

> "The sense development has been extraordinary, even for an adj." [Weekley] -- from "timid" (pre-1300); to "fussy, fastidious" (late 14c.); to "dainty, delicate" (c.1400); to "precise, careful" (1500s, preserved in such terms as a nice distinction  and nice and early ); to "agreeable, delightful" (1769); to "kind, thoughtful" (1830). In 16c.-17c. it is often difficult to determine exactly what is meant when a writer uses this word.

Its meaning changed to become "agreeable" over a long period of time, and now, the reason for its connotation(wishy-washy sense) [in modern times:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nice)

> If any criticism is valid, it might be that the word is used too often and has become a cliché lacking the qualities of precision and intensity that are embodied in many of its synonyms.

Answer (score 9):

It really depends on what you mean by "originally". We can trace the word back at least as far as a Proto-Indo-European form "skei" meaning 'cut', 'split' (i.e. about 5,000-6,000 years ago). This developed into various Latin words, including "scindere" (from which we get the English word "rescind", and which has become "scinder" in French still meaning something like 'to divide'), and also 'scire' ("to know" < "to split/distinguish truth from falsehood"). In Latin, 'scire' could be combined with the prefix 'ne-' ("not"), to give 'nescire' ("to not know about", "be ignorant of"), leading to the adjective 'nescius' ("ignorant"), which was the word eventually borrowed into English and which then gradually changed its meaning.

So if your notion of "original" is "originally appeared as a word that was ostensibly 'English'", then the meaning was probably close to 'ignorant', 'foolish'. But the origin of the word can be traced back much further than that. But then, there's nothing hugely magical linguistically speaking about Proto-Indo-European (or Latin, for that matter)--they're just arbitrary points (or rather, vaguely-bounded time periods) in history when we're able to posit something about the form of language that existed. Presumably the Indo-European form "skei" that we believe existed around 6,000 years ago itself developed from something, but we can't say exactly what. So in a strict sense, we can't say that this or anything else was the "original" form/meaning.

This is why arguments of the "well, this word really means X because that was the original meaning" type are generally spurious.

As to why it changed its meaning: well, in a sense, this word hasn't done anything remarkable. It's the normal state of affairs for words to change their meanings over time, and largely the more remarkable cases are words that have (e.g. because they're highly technical words usually consulted alongside their original, arbitrary intended interpretation whenever they are used) retained their 'original' interpretation.

Comment: "As to why it changed its meaning: well, in a sense, this word hasn't done anything remarkable. It's the normal state of affairs for ..." answers to appeal to ignorance, to let the own ignorance seem less sever. But let's not ignore that you are going on, what, 30 mins of research, and fall in with the crowd pretending that the word had one and only one primary sense that just about slowly changed. You haven't sampled frequently enough to show an infinitesimal growth factor, no. You sampled sporadicly and so couldn't prove anything but an aliased low frequency signal.

Comment: So to some extent what you say is true: a severe limitation that we have is that what we are going off broad snapshots or samples of the state of affairs at sparse, irregular points in time, as summarised or deduced by particular dictionary writers or scholars. Or put another way, an aliased low frequency signal is pretty much what we have to go on. In fact it's even worse than that: when we talk about PIE, we haven't even really got any signal... But I'm not sure how that really negates my argument-- if anything, it reinforces it, I would have thought.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting.

An entry on [amelioration](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/amelioraterm.htm) (which is the upgrading or elevation of a word's meaning, as when a word with a negative sense develops a positive one.) specifically mentions **nice** as an example that has changed meaning since its original

> •"The word nice is a classic example
>   of amelioration . . .. This is a rare
>   occurrence, compared with the opposite
>   process of pejoration, or downgrading.
>
> "The meaning of nice when it first
>   appeared in Middle English (about
>   1300) was '(of persons or their
>   actions) foolish, silly, simple;
>   ignorant, senseless, absurd.'
>
> " . . . A shift away from
>   disparagement began in the 1500s, with
>   such meanings as 'requiring or
>   involving great precision or
>   accuracy.' . . .
>
> "The movement toward amelioration
>   reached its apex in the 1800s with
>   such meanings as 'kind and
>   considerate, friendly.'" (Sol
>   Steinmetz, Semantic Antics: How and
>   Why Words Change Meanings. Random
>   House, 2008)

Answer (score 5):

## History of *nice*:

**Nice** is a highly polysemous word. A [*polysemous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) word has more than one meaning.

**Origin:** *Ne-* (not) + *scire* (know, same root as 'science') -> *nescire* (not know) -> *nescius* (ignorant) -> *nice* (careless, clumsy, stupid - late 13c). In 14th century, its meaning was *foolish, ignorant* and *stupid* ---> ***semantic change (amelioration)*** ---> *fastidious* (late 14c) -> *precise, careful* (1500's) -> *agreeable, delightful* (1769) -> *kind, thoughtful* (1830's) -> *pleasant, agreeable* and then *respectable* (19c) -> *pleasant* and other positive meanings (20c onwards).

*Nice* and another English word *[nescience](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nescient)* (meaning: *ignorant*) have the same origin (nescire).

## Brief answer:

It was borrowed from French, meaning silly and stupid. Years later, nice meant *dissolute* or *extravagant in dress* and *fashionable*. From there, the word went on to mean finely dressed or precise about looks. And then, precise about looks changed to precise about reputation.
As time went on, 'nice' meant something like  *to have a refined taste*. From here, the positive connotations continued with the idea of *being cultured, respectable and agreeable*.

Finally, after this perplexing history, 'nice' remains a term of approval today. We use it all the time to compliment people.

It entered Modern English through Old French and Middle English from Latin so its meaning has changed over time. This is because of **semantic change**.

---

## Explanation:

From Merriam Webster:

> It is a bit difficult to say with much certainty what the earliest meaning of nice was in Modern English, since by the end of the 14th century there were already a number of different senses of the word — **[M-W]**

#### Some other meanings of 'nice':

- **'Nice' has meant 'tarty':**

> Sometimes it went further than this pejorative sense - it had the sense of the modern British slang 'tarty', or '[appropriate to] a woman of promiscuous sexual behaviour'.) — **[[AWE]](http://hull-awe.org.uk/index.php/Nice_(changing_meaning))**

- **'Nice' has meant 'fastidious' (around 1500):**

> Its second main meaning was that of 'precise' or 'fastidious' — **[AWE]**

- **'Nice' has meant 'dissolute'**:

> May we not this day read our sin in our punishment? O what nice and wanton appetites, what curious and itching ears, had thy people in the dayes of plenty? - John Flavel, Husbandry Spiritualized, 1674 — **[M-W]**

- **'Nice' has meant 'chaste':**

> “But Reddy Wheeler knew Daisy. We were properly introduced. It was quite all right!”
> “Yes, but nice girls don’t do this sort of thing, you know--unchaperoned, and so late at night, and all that.” - Fred Jackson, “Young Blood,” Munsey’s Magazine, 1917 — **[M-W]**

**'Nice' has meant 'finicky':**

> By the 16th century, the sense of being "very particular" or "finicky" had developed — **[[Word Central]](http://wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student_clean?va=nice)**

---

#### Why did the meaning of 'nice' change:

The meaning of *nice* changed because of a common phenomenon called **Semantic change**.

#### Semantic change

In semantics and historical linguistics, semantic change refers to any change in the meaning(s) of a word over the course of time. Also called *semantic shift*, *lexical change*, and *semantic progression*. Common types of semantic change include amelioration, pejoration, broadening, semantic narrowing, bleaching, metaphor, and metonymy.

#### 1. Amelioration:

When a word with negative meaning develops a positive meaning, the process is called 'amelioration'.

The literal meaning of ameliorate is *to make something unpleasant better*.

**Example:** The best example of *amelioration* is 'nice'.
'Nice' had negative meanings (*ignorant, stupid and silly* in 14th century), now it's used in positive sense (*pleasant, excellent, admirable* etc).

The opposite of *amelioration* is *pejoration*

#### 2. Pejoration:

When a word with positive meaning develops a negative meaning, the process is called 'pejoration'.

The literal meaning of pejorate is *to make something worse*.

**Example:**

A very common example of *pejoration* is the word 'gay'.

'Gay' originally meant *lighthearted* and *joyous* in 13th century. In 14th century, its meaning was *bright and showy*. It acquired negative connotations (immorality) around 1637. Presently, it's used to mean *homosexual*. See how it developed negative meaning. It's called *pejoration*.

### References:

- [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/nice-multiple-meanings)
- [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/nice-guys/)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change)
- [ADW Blog](http://blog.adw.org/2015/11/the-not-so-nice-origins-and-meanings-of-the-word-nice/)
- [Maitland Mercury](https://www.maitlandmercury.com.au/story/5050529/the-intriguing-evolution-behind-the-word-nice/)
- [Amelioration - ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/amelioration-word-meanings-1689082)
- [Mental Floss](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/61876/11-words-meanings-have-changed-drastically-over-time)
- [ADW blog](http://blog.adw.org/2015/11/the-not-so-nice-origins-and-meanings-of-the-word-nice/)

Answer (score 4):

This is what the NOAD says:

> ORIGIN Middle English (in the sense [stupid] ): from Old French, from Latin **nescius** ‘*ignorant*,’ from **nescire** ‘*not know*.’
>    Other early senses included [coy, reserved,] giving rise to [fastidious, scrupulous] : this led both to the sense [fine, subtle] (regarded by some as the “correct” sense), and to the main current senses.

But the OED says that the meanings transformation is not very clear:

> *The precise development of the very divergent senses which this word has acquired in English is not altogether clear. In many examples from the 16th and 17th centuries it is difficult to say in what particular sense the writer intended it to be taken.*

Answer (score 4):

As noted by Etymonline:

***[Nice:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/nice)***

> ***The sense development has been extraordinary***, even for an adj." [Weekley] -- from "timid, faint-hearted" (pre-1300); to "fussy, fastidious" (late 14c.); to "dainty, delicate" (c. 1400); to "precise, careful" (1500s, preserved in such terms as a nice distinction and nice and early); to "agreeable, delightful" (1769); to "kind, thoughtful" (1830).
>
> By 1926, it was pronounced "too great a favorite with the ladies, who have charmed out of it all its individuality and converted it into a mere diffuser of vague and mild agreeableness." [Fowler]

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/nice-guys/) offers more details about the evolution of its meaning:

> Nice, it turns out, began as a negative term derived from the Latin nescius, meaning “unaware, ignorant.” This sense of “ignorant” was carried over into English when the word was first borrowed (via French) in the early 1300s. And for almost a century, nice was used to characterize a “stupid, ignorant, or foolish” person.
>
> Starting in the late 1300s, nice began to refer to “conduct, a person, or clothing that was considered excessively luxurious or lascivious.” However, by the 1400s a new, more neutral sense of nice was emerging. At this time, nice began to refer to “a person who was finely dressed, someone who was scrupulous, or something that was precise or fussy.”
>
> By the late 1500s, nice was further softening, describing something as “refined, culture,” especially used of polite society.
>
> The high value placed on being coy, delicate, and reserved was instrumental in the semantic amelioration of the term nice in the late 18th and early 19th centuries.
>
> Jane Austen, for instance, mocked this now-positive term in Northanger Abbey (1817) when Henry Tilney teases the naive Catherine Morland for her overuse of nice. He jokes: “… and this is a very nice day, and we are taking a very nice walk, and you are two very nice young ladies. Oh, it is a very nice word, indeed!—it does for everything.

Comment: Thank you Hachi for your time. Actually I wanted to know why its meaning changed. If you search "origin of nice" in google you will get many results in which Etymonline is first and Dictionary.com is second. Thanks again for your time but I am sorry I can't accept this answer.. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=origin+of+nice&rlz=1C1CHBD_enPK893PK893&oq=origin+of+nice&aqs=chrome..69i57.3631j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I had already read all these but I wanted to know why its meaning changed which Decaptiated Soul has explained thoroughly in their answer.

Comment: @EverywhereEnglish I offered no speculation on why the term had such dramatic semantic shift through the centuries. We actually don’t know and any assumption is just  as good as any other. Just read the facts.

Comment: I thanked you for that. I am sorry again. Maybe my question was too vague. But also these results were present on top in first Google search. Just read the facts.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot improve upon [Decapitated Soul](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/365490/decapitated-soul)'s excellent answer, but I also cannot resist including a snapshot of a moment in the evolution of "nice" from "to have a refined taste" to a more general term of approbation.  This exchange from Jane Austen's *Northanger Abbey* (written in 1803, published 1818) shows the hero teasing the (less educated) heroine for her use of "nice":

> “Henry,” said Miss Tilney, “you are very impertinent. Miss Morland, he is treating you exactly as he does his sister. He is forever finding fault with me, for some incorrectness of language, and now he is taking the same liberty with you. The word 'nicest,' as you used it, did not suit him; and you had better change it as soon as you can, or we shall be overpowered with Johnson and Blair all the rest of the way.”
>
> “I am sure,” cried Catherine, “I did not mean to say anything wrong; but it is a nice book, and why should not I call it so?”
>
> “Very true,” said Henry, “and this is a very nice day, and we are taking a very nice walk, and you are two very nice young ladies. Oh! It is a very nice word indeed! It does for everything. Originally perhaps it was applied only to express neatness, propriety, delicacy, or refinement—people were nice in their dress, in their sentiments, or their choice. But now every commendation on every subject is comprised in that one word.”
>
> “While, in fact,” cried his sister, “it ought only to be applied to you, without any commendation at all. You are more nice than wise."

It's kind of *nice* to consider that even Henry was mistaken to think his preferred meaning was the "original" when his definition was already a considerable way through its semantic wanderings!