# Why king and queen rather than king and kingess?

Tags: etymology, history, analogy

Dukes have duchesses, counts countesses, princes princesses, mayors mayoresses, and even emperors empresses. Yet *kings* have *queens* rather than say, *kingesses*. Why is this so? If this was due to some historical quirk of fate, was there ever a word similar to *kingess* which was superseded by *queen*?

How about *lords*, *ladies*, and ... *lordesses*?

Comment: Gentlemanesses...

Comment: @MrLister [Gentlewoman](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gentlewoman).

Comment: The general answer to any question about why certain sets of words aren't as regular as they could be is that language is not evolved to be efficient and regular. It's evolved to be successful in communicating in variable environments, and that involves a vast amount of redundancy; spoken language is more than 90% redundant. Irregularity of very common words helps a lot with that. Irregularity is a design feature, not a bug. Otherwise we'd all be speaking [Volapük](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/volapukverb.html)

Comment: @JohnLawler Quite so. And understanding the reasons behind said design features make them even more pleasing :) Thanks for the [Volapük](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volap%C3%BCk) reference. That's hilarious.

Comment: That kind of evolution shows off in the [grammaticalization cycle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grammaticalization.pdf)

Comment: Flawed premiss: there are no counts in Britain (only earls), but the female equivalent is still *countess*. History trumps logic any time.

Comment: Migrate to [Chess.SE](http://chess.stackexchange.com/?as=1)? (Sorry, couldn't resist...)

Comment: @TimLymington I don't see any mention of either Britain or earls in my question :) Interesting point re: countess/earless; perhaps it would have been misread as _ear-less_? Let me make that into a question.

Comment: As to Esperanto you would be right. But English  isn't Esperanto.

Answer (score 11):

*Queen* has its origins in a pre-English word meaning simply ‘wife’. Beyond that, we need to look for anthropological and social, rather than linguistic, reasons why a king’s wife should not have had a more distinctive description.

*Lord* comes from Old English *hláford*, meaning ‘keeper of the bread’. Since this was presumably a role denied women, the need for a feminine form didn’t arise.

Comment: Does *queen* predate *king*? If not, was there perhaps an earlier term to signify the king's significant other?

Comment: @coleopterist. The OED’s earliest citation for _king_, or, rather, its Old English equivalent, is from the ninth century in the Anglo-Saxon Chronicle. There seem to be no reliable dates for the first occurrence of _queen_, other than that it, too, is found in Old English.

Comment: English _queen_, like _quean_, Celtic _Gwen_, and Greek _gyn-_, among others, are from the [PIE root _*gwen-_ 'woman'](http://web.archive.org/web/20080627204018/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE182.html)

Comment: Earlier *hlafweard* was the "loaf-ward", the guardian of the bread, and "lady" < *hlæfdige*, "loaf-maid", ultimately the kneader of the loaf.

Comment: @StoneyB. Yes, of course, very good point.

Comment: @John: Please can you give an example of such a Celtic Gwen? I can only find the Welsh name [gwen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gwen_(given_name)): the feminine form of gwyn ("white, bright, fair, pure, blessed, holy"), from Proto-Celtic *windos (“white”). (Perhaps ultimately from PIE *weid-,  to know/see, or *wę̄d-r ‘water’.)

Comment: Yes, it's the name _Gwen_. There may be other etymology as well; there was considerable sharing among roots, and chance resemblances are always useful for adaptation. I'm just quoting the AHD. As I recall, Buck has quite a long article about it.

Comment: My theory is that wife supplanted queen to reffer to a woman. After a time queen became archaic and used only in formal contexts, such as referring to the king's wife. Eventually people forgot its original usage and it became associated only with the king's wife.

Comment: Note, that there is an important difference between a 'Queen' as the wife of a ruling monarch and a 'Queen' who is the ruling monarch (and not the wife of a King). The husband of a 'Queen' who is the ruling monarch is not usually a 'King', but will have some other lower title so that there is no doubt who is the head of state.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the origins of the words.

#### *-ess* words

All the words that end in *-ess* came to English with the Norman Invasion from French and Latin. In fact, the suffix *-ess* is itself [derived from French ***-esse***](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=-ess&ref=searchbar_searchhint). So words ending in *-ess* are of French origin. Almost all of them came to be used from Middle English (ME) onwards:

- duchess: from ME *[duchesse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duchesse#Middle_English)*
- goddess: from ME *[goddesse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goddesse#Middle_English)*
- princess: from ME *[princesse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/princesse#Middle_English)* etc.

*King* and *queen* on the other hand come from Anglo-Saxon.

#### *King* and *queen*

*King* and *queen* are both native English words--Anglo-Saxon words:

- king comes from Old English *cyning* (alt. *cyng*)
- queen comes from Old English *cwēn*

*cwēn* originally meant a wife, [specifically that of a king or another important man](https://books.google.com/books?id=J4i3zV4vnBAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=origins%20of%20words%20and%20phrases&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/queen#etymonline_v_3172) says that the original sense (i.e. *wife*) has been specialized by Old English to *wife of a king*.

Larry Trask suggests that the current meaning of 'queen' is 'improved' because of '[Melioration](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/535259/365490)' ([Semantic change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change)). Melioration is an improvement in meaning. He says that *queen* formerly just meant 'woman', but today it means *queen* (the female monarch of a kingdom). [[Trask's Historical Linguistcs](https://books.google.com/books/about/Trask_s_Historical_Linguistics.html?id=mQZSAQAAIAAJ)]

In summary, all the *-ess* words are French/Latinate words while *king* and *queen* are native words and don't take these endings.

Comment: Excellent Anwer. I had no idea that all "-ess" words were French. And that transition from woman/wife to queen is very interesting. Now I need to go read about Melioration.

Answer (score 0):

"Queen" comes from "Quenna" (the wife of "Quenno") in protoceltic language (perhaps 500 BC. Quenno is the "head" (Head/Leader of Warriors/Soldiers). The Quenno is not the King! King is a protogermanic idiom (Kuningaz). The wife of the "Kuning(az) is "Kuningin". The celtic King is "Rigs" (latin = rex). Because a "King" is everytime the "Regent", but not his wife.

Comment: This would be improved with some supporting references.

Comment: Does this address the question, _why_ there isn't a derived feminine of king, as with prince/princess; duke/duchess; count/countess ... emperor/empress?

Comment: The standard etymology for "queen" traces it from the Germanic branch of Indo-European. Can you cite a source for the statement that it was derived instead from a Celtic word?

Comment: Yes. My source is the university of wales (Prifysgol Cymru).

 Look the link: https://www.wales.ac.uk/en/CentreforAdvancedWelshCelticStudies/ResearchProjects/CompletedProjects/TheCelticLanguagesandCulturalIdentity/CelticLexicon.aspx

Comment: Protoceltic: *kʷenno- (Quenno) = Head, *kʷenno-tamiko = Lord. "-o" is masculinum and "-a" femininum

Comment: That source says that *kʷenno- can be reconstructed as the Proto-Celtic root for "head". It doesn't however support the statement in this answer that the English word "queen" comes from this Proto-Celtic root. Is that a conclusion you came to on your own?

Answer (score -2):

*[Queen](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/queen)* is a very old word. It has been in English since before 900. There was never a *kingess*. The term *queen* is related to Greek  *gynḗ* (woman) and probably to Latin *re-gin-a* meaning queen.

Comment: The Greek connection seems to be correct, but I think Latin *regina* is actually the "reg" word root meaning "king" (seen also in the word for king *rex*,*regis*) plus a feminizing suffix "-ina."

Answer (score -2):

This is pure conjecture, but I think it's because there is only one. In the peerages of British nobility, there could be multiples of all other nobles, but there could only be one King and Queen.  It stands to reason that her name would be unique and individual.

Comment: What about the honorary titles Sir versus Dame? There can be multiple "Sirs" and "Dames".

Comment: Please support suppositions with evidence, and maybe add a clarificatory note, perhaps you are referring to why "today" we have a separate word for His Majesty "king" and another for Her Majesty "queen". Are you or are you referring to their etymologies? In which case please read Barie England's answer.