# Why is the feminine equivalent of an earl a countess rather than an earless?

Tags: etymology, history, analogy

A [comment by Tim Lymington](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100567/why-king-and-queen-rather-than-king-and-kingess#comment204164_100567) notes that the wife of an [earl](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/earl) is a *countess*. Why is this so? Shouldn't it have been *earless*? Was this perhaps a conscious decision due to its homography with [ear-less](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ear?q=earless#ear__36)?

Did a [jarl](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jarl?q=jarl) ever have a *jarless*? Ah. Perhaps not.

Comment: _-ess_ is a suffix from French; the most common Germanic suffix is _-in_, so if there were an inherited feminine form of _jarl_ it would probably be _jarlin_. One can speculate that this would have come into English as _earlen_ (the only desinence of _-in_ I can think of in English is _vixen_, from _fox_).

Answer (score 5):

The male version of *countess* is sometimes *count*. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count):

> The word count came into English from the French comte, itself from Latin comes—in its accusative comitem— meaning "companion", and later "companion of
>   the emperor, delegate of the emperor". The
>   adjective form of the word is "comital". The British and Irish equivalent is an earl (whose wife is a "countess", for lack of an English term).

An *earl* was originally another title, but later came to be equivalent to *count*:

> [An earl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl) is a member of the nobility. The title is Anglo-Saxon, akin to the Scandinavian form jarl, and meant "chieftain", particularly a chieftain set to rule a territory in a king's stead. In Scandinavia, it became obsolete in the Middle Ages and was replaced with duke (hertig/hertug). In later medieval Britain, it became the equivalent of the
>   continental count (in England in the earlier period, it was more akin to duke; in Scotland it assimilated the concept of mormaer). ...
>
> The Norman-derived equivalent "count" was not introduced following the Norman Conquest of England though "countess" was and is used for the female title. As Geoffrey Hughes writes, "It is a
>   likely speculation that the Norman French title
>   'Count' was abandoned in England in favour of
>   the Germanic 'Earl' […] precisely because of the
>   uncomfortable phonetic proximity to cunt".

Comment: To further complicate things: "An earl has the title Earl of [X] when the title
originates from a placename, or Earl [X] when the
title comes from a surname. In either case, he is
referred to as Lord [X], and his wife as Lady [X]. A countess who holds an earldom in her own right
also uses Lady [X], but her husband does not have
a title (unless he has one in his own right)."

Comment: Thanks! So, the reason is "for lack of a better term"? How dull :( Any idea what female _jarls_ were called?

Comment: As far as I can tell, jarls were only men with no special title for their wives, although the first ever female Guizer Jarl was chosen in 2010, there's no mention of a feminine title.  http://www.shetlandtimes.co.uk/2010/11/01/up-helly-a-history-as-first-female-guizer-jarl-is-chosen (But this actual title only dates from 1906, the role was only created in 1881, and some say it's "based upon a flawed Viking perspective".)

Comment: Before the title died out, *jarl* was also used for a higher rank in Scandinavia, including rulers of petty kingdoms. I imagine it is for this reason that we normally translate *Greve* and *Lensgreve* as *Count* rather than *Earl* even though the latter would be a more "complete" translation into English.

Comment: So referring to, for example, Charles Spencer, brother of Diana, in a sentence, one would use his name, "Charles Spencer", as I just did, or "Lord Spencer", but not "Earl Spencer"? Example, "I was in Marks and Sparks the other day when I happened to see Lord Spencer shopping for unmentionables". Not  "I was in Marks and Sparks the other day when I happened to see Earl Spencer...". Is that right? Or is it "the Earl Spencer", with the definite article? Is Lord/Lady [X] a form of address only?

Answer (score 2):

As Hugo cites in his Wikipedia reference, the title of earl is derived from the Anglo-Saxon title. An *eorl* was the highest rank below the king in pre-Norman England, and there was no female version of the word. Indeed, the only female noble who had a title at all was the *cyninge* (queen). There existed a kind of abstract title, but it was pretty broad:

> **ides** *f* (-e/-a) virgin; 2 woman, wife, lady, queen; [it is a word little used except in poetry, and it is supposed by Grimm to have been applied, in the earliest times, like the Greek numfé, to superhuman beings, occupying a position between goddesses and mere women]

In all my reading about the period I have never encountered a female title of rank corresponding to *eorl* (itself replacing *ealdorman*). Indeed, even the famous wife of Eorl Leofric of Mercia, whom you know as Lady Godiva (1004-1080), is simply referred to by her given name, *Godgifu*.

Given that there was no traditional corresponding title of rank, it is not surprising that one should have been borrowed.