# Nice came from nescius meaning stupid?

Tags: etymology

I came across an odd thing. I searched "nice" in Lexico and see what it says about its origin: *Middle English (in the sense **‘stupid’**): from Old French, from Latin nescius **‘ignorant’**, from nescire **‘not know’**. Other early senses included ‘coy, reserved’, giving rise to ‘fastidious, scrupulous’: this led both to the sense ‘fine, subtle’ (regarded by some as the ‘correct’ sense), and to the main current senses.*

https://www.lexico.com/definition/nice

**How did it take the meaning of "Giving pleasure or satisfaction; pleasant or attractive"?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the origins of the word "nice"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31368/what-are-the-origins-of-the-word-nice) '... what are the origins of this word? What did it originally mean? Why has the meaning changed so much through the years?'